# how to validate a number contains current year

Tags: jquery, validation, numbers

I have a problem that one of my form feild has Roll no  should be of the format YY-XXX

YY    - last two digits of the current year

XXX - three digit number

how to validate this type of numbers using jquery?

Comment: can you exactly give one format with example

Comment: have you tried anything yet?? Use regex in this case but try b4 asking again do some google

Comment: regex is trash, DONT EVER USE IT

Answer (score 1):

Use RegExp `/\d{2}-\d{3}/`, [RegExp reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
console.log(/\d{2}-\d{3}/.test('12-123')) // true
console.log(/\d{2}-\d{3}/.test('ab-123')) // false
```